# Where to find Nuget package for TeamsFx .NET SDK

Tags: .net, sdk, microsoft-teams

The [Getting Started](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/tree/dev/packages/dotnet-sdk#getting-started) section for [TeamsFx .NET SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/tree/dev/packages/dotnet-sdk) indicates that I should be able to find a Nuget package named `Microsoft.TeamsFx`. However, I cannot find such a a package, not even when searching for prerelease packages.

Am I missing something here, or is it just a matter of the package not being published yet? The source code is not that old yet.

Comment: Looks  like project went live yesterday,
Could you please check the similar ask & reply in below question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927592/any-net-sdk-for-for-accessing-context-within-microsoft-teams-tab

Comment: Still waiting for the Nuget package for `Microsoft.TeamsFx` to be published on Nuget. For the moment, it's not that big of a deal, since I can get the reference to the library by downloading the source code and including the project in my application.

Eventually, we will probably get the Nuget package too.

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from comments section for more visibility:

Nuget package for Microsoft.TeamsFx has not published on Nuget and also we do not have exact ETA. For the moment, user can get the reference to the library by downloading the source code and including the project in application. Eventually, we will probably get the Nuget package too.
[Source code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/tree/dev/packages/dotnet-sdk)